# Why plugin z of zsh is not active inside the .zshrc?

Tags: zsh

I installed oh my zsh and zsh auto suggestion. Then I read here (https://www.sitepoint.com/zsh-tips-tricks/) about z zsh, an interesting plugin. And I really wanted to install it. So I put the plugin inside my .zshrc file. But the plugin feature is not active, it's not yellow like source command or alias (and those are properly working). I tried to change place of the plugin line (after / before source), but it didn't work. I did'nt understand the first line. My .zshrc, if someone could help...:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export ZSH="/home/yanalolux/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME="ys"
. /home/yanalolux/z.sh

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
plugins=(z zsh-autosuggestions)
plugins=(zsh-autosuggestions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.zshrc` you have the following two lines:

```
plugins=(z zsh-autosuggestions)
plugins=(zsh-autosuggestions)
```

The second line remove the z plugin. You should have only one line with:

```
plugins=(z zsh-autosuggestions)
```

According to the [ZSH-z plugin Github homepage](https://github.com/agkozak/zsh-z):

> ZSH-z is a command line tool that allows you to jump quickly to directories that you have visited frequently in the past, or recently -- but most often a combination of the two (a concept known as ["frecency"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frecency)). It works by keeping track of when you go to directories and how much time you spend in them. It is then in the position to guess where you want to go when you type a partial string, e.g. `z src` might take you to `~/src/zsh`.

Comment: The plugins word remains in green color. It is not active.

Comment: The purpose of the ZSH-z plugin is not to change colors of words. See my updated answer.